# How to assign and retrieve value from the GridView Cell using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have Two Labels such as FixedTotal and TotalPercent, One GridView which has One Row such as

```
    ReferenceID       Percentage          Amount
   --------------    -------------       --------
        1                5                 1000
```

Here I want to change the "Percentage" Column value 5 with the TotalPercent label's text.
and I want to display the "Amount" Column value 1000 in the FixedTotal label.
I also want to check whether the Grid has row or not? How to do this?
The Columns are BoundField Columns..

Comment: How do you want to initiate the change?  Is there a column with an "update" button?  Are you trying to add up all of the amounts or use a specific row amount?

Comment: @Alison: The Percentage in the "TotalPercent" Label may change according to one Button Click event. So the Percentage Specified in the label should replace the Percentage column value in the GridView. By the Percentage the Amount will change and the Amount will be displayed in to the "FixedTotal" Label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Getting/Setting` value to gridview cells, you need to know the `Row Index` of Gridview, you can `pass row index` when you call JS function from gridview

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function update(rowIndexOfGridview) {
    var ri = rowIndexOfGridview; 
    var grd = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

    CellValue = grd.rows[ri].cells[1].childNodes[0].value; // get
    grd.rows[ri].cells[2].childNodes[0].value = CellValue; assign
    ...........
    .............
}
```

Comment: Hi Akhtar, While assigning it shows "The Object does not support this property" and While retrieving it gets "undefined" value.

Comment: Follow the answer and try to understand the Javascript first, It should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function Calculate() 
<br/>
{ 
<br/>
var grid = document.getElementById("<%=GridID.ClientID%>");
<br/> 
var sum = 0; <br/>
for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++)<br/>
 { <br/>
var Cell = grid.rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input"); 
<br/>if (!Cell[4].value) {sum  += 0; } else { sum += parseFloat(Cell[4].value);} } 
<br/>
document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value = sum; 
 }
<br/>
 </script>
------------------------------------------------------------------------



<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current payment" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="cridnvalue" runat="server" Width="70px" BorderStyle="None" onkeyup="CalculateTax();" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="120px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. I have used this and has no error.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function update(rowIndexOfGridview) {
    var ri = rowIndexOfGridview; 
    var grd = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

    var CellValue = grd.rows[ri].cells[1].childNodes[0].textContent); // get
    grd.rows[ri].cells[2].childNodes[0].textContent = CellValue; //assign
}
</script>
```

Comment: What you did harms all SO users. Read [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)